# ArcGIS Python Toolbox expression on Portal (Web Tool in Web App) problem

Tags: python, python-toolbox, geoprocessing-service, arcgis-custom-widget

I wrote a GP tool (Python toolbox) with Expression using GPSQLExpression with updateParameters that manipulates the expression,

[image: In ArcGIS Pro]

it works fine on ArcGIS Pro (2.4), but it becomes a String Input on Web App (Geoprocessing Tools widget)

[image: in Geoprocessing widget setting]

after publishing as Web Tool.

[image: Widget]

Any idea how to make it looks like a normal expression GUI with selections?

```
def getParameterInfo(self):
    """Define parameter definitions"""
    ReferenceFeature = arcpy.Parameter(name="ReferenceFeature",
                             displayName = "Reference Feature",
                             parameterType = "Required",
                             direction = "Input",
                             datatype="GPFeatureRecordSetLayer")
    ReferenceFeature.value = r'C:\temp\MyProject3.gdb\Points'

    SearchDistance = arcpy.Parameter(name="SearchDistance",
                             displayName = "Search Buffer Distance",
                             parameterType = "Required",
                             datatype="GPLong")
    SearchDistance.value = self.distance

    BuildingAgeRange = arcpy.Parameter(name="BuildingAgeRange",
                             displayName = "Building Age Range",
                             parameterType = "Required",
                             datatype="GPLong")
    BuildingAgeRange.value=self.ageRange

    SearchLayer = arcpy.Parameter(name="SearchLayer",
                             displayName = "Search Layer",
                             parameterType = "Required",
                             direction = "Input",
                             datatype="GPFeatureLayer")

    SelectedArea = arcpy.Parameter(name="SelectedArea",
                             displayName = "Manual Select Area",
                             parameterType = "Optional",
                             direction = "Input",
                             datatype="GPFeatureRecordSetLayer")
    SelectedArea.value=r'C:\temp\MyProject3.gdb\manual_select'

    
    outputLayer = arcpy.Parameter(name="outputLayer",
                             displayName = "Output Feature",
                             parameterType = "Required",
                             direction = "Output",
                             datatype="GPFeatureLayer")
    outputLayer.value = self.output

    boundary = arcpy.Parameter(name="boundary",
                             displayName = "Output Boundary",
                             parameterType = "Optional",
                             direction = "Output",
                             datatype="GPFeatureLayer")
    boundary.value = self.outputBoundary
    expression= arcpy.Parameter(name="expression",
                             displayName = "Expression",
                             parameterType = "Required",
                             direction = "Input",
                             datatype="GPSQLExpression")

    expression.parameterDependencies = [SearchLayer.name]

    params =[ReferenceFeature,SearchDistance, BuildingAgeRange,SearchLayer, SelectedArea, outputLayer, boundary,expression]

    return params


def checkRefBuilding(self, fc, point):
    fields=['A','L','R','M']

    whereclause=''
    a=0
    l=''
    r = ''
    m=''
    selectReference = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(fc,'INTERSECT',point,'','NEW_SELECTION')
    if int(arcpy.GetCount_management(selectReference).getOutput(0))>0:
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(selectReference, fields) as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                a=row[0]
                l=row[1]
                r=row[2]
                m=row[3]
        a, whereclause=self.checkData(a, 0, whereclause,fc,fields)
        l, whereclause=self.checkData(l, 1,whereclause,fc,fields)
        r, whereclause=self.checkData(r, 2,whereclause,fc,fields) 
        m, whereclause=self.checkData(m, 3,whereclause,fc,fields)
    return whereclause

def updateParameters(self, parameters):

    whereclause=''
    fc=parameters[3].valueAsText
    point = parameters[0].value
    if parameters[0].altered and parameters[3].altered:
        whereclause = self.checkRefBuilding(fc,point)
    if parameters[0].altered and not parameters[0].value is None and not parameters[3].value is None and parameters[7].hasBeenValidated:
        whereclause = self.checkRefBuilding(fc,point)
        if parameters[7].altered:
            whereclause=parameters[7].value
        parameters[7].value=whereclause
        

    if parameters[7].altered:
        whereclause=parameters[7].value
    if parameters[7].hasBeenValidated:
        parameters[7].value=whereclause

    return


def checkData(self, data, num, where, fc,fields):
    ageRange=self.ageRange
    if ageRange is None:
        ageRange = 0
    if not data is None:

        if len(where)<1:
            if num==0:
                where="""{0} >= {1} and {2} <= {3}""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, fields[num]),data-ageRange,arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, fields[num]),data+ageRange)
            else:
                where="""{0} = '{1}'""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, fields[num]),data)
        else:
            where=where+""" and {0} = '{1}'""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, fields[num]),data)


    return data, where
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Please [edit] your question to include a snippet of your code that works in ArcGIS Pro but doesn't work as a web tool.  Include details on how you've set it up and run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simply**: With a lot of custom JavaScript code you'll write for Web AppBuilder.

**Longer answer**:

Geoprocessing Services / Web Tools only support a limited set of input and output types. The type "SQL Expression" isn't supported as-is. It IS supported as a STRING. When you use an un-supported type in a GP Service, the publish process will attempt to map your parameter to a supported type. Which 99% of the time is either STRING or CONSTANT (constant meaning it can't support it the type in any good way, thus hardcodes it). From your screen shot, you can see that the input is GPString now. Your only option here is to figure out the best approach of supported input GP Service parameter types and out of the box functionality of Web AppBuilder. (Unless you want to write custom code to completely design a nice UI for your tool).

I actually wrote about this scenario a couple years ago and used select with an expression as an example in the [Designing Geoprocessing Services blog](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/analytics/analytics/designing-geoprocessing-services/). I'd give it it a read. It doesn't provide any one, single answer, but it does talk about options and strategies.

Comment: Thanks! Writing JavaScript means customizing widget? It will be slightly harder and will take longer time to develop. Are there any tutorial for customizing widget that you would recommend?

Comment: Someone put out a select by attribute widget that you can find here: https://github.com/AdriSolid/WAB-Custom-Widgets - you could take that, and the out of the box geoprocessing widget and mash them into a single widget. (Using the Select widget for the UI and the GP widget for the back end submission). If this is your first jump into web appbuilder development, its going to be tough for you as this isn't a beginner task. If you're a proficient JS developer, you should be able to ramp up with a bit of reading.

Comment: Great thanks! I’m not a JS developer, it will take a while for me to digest all these code So its still possible to add the Expression like UI for my GP tool? i will check out the github, thanks!